# Log in multiple users

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a log in with multiple users. I have a welcome sheet with cells specifically for the username and password and a sheet with the username and password combinations.

I'm getting an error at `If wk.Range("B3").Value = ws.Range(i, "A").Value Then`
it says "object defined" error.

I thought it made sense to just try to check if the string in the cell matched a username/password in the users sheet through a loop. 
I'm not sure if I'm going about it right. And then depending on if you log in as an operator or another user it affects which sheets you see.

```
Public CurrentUser As String, CurrentRole As String, LoginUserName As String, LoginPassword As String
Public LoginStatus As Boolean

Sub Login()
'Worksheets("Users").Activate
Dim numberOfUsers, i As Integer
Dim ws, wk As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Users")
Set wk = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Welcome")

numberOfUsers = ws.Range("Users").Rows.Count
LoginStatus = False


For i = 1 To numberOfUsers
If wk.Range("B3").Value = ws.Range(i, "A").Value Then
  If wk.Range("B4").Value = ws.Range(i, "B").Value Then
  CurrentUser = wk.Range("B3").Value
  LoginStatus = True
  Else
  LoginStatus = False
  MsgBox ("Wrong Login Data")
  End If
Else
LoginStatus = False
MsgBox ("Wrong Login Data")
Next i`

Select Case CurrentUser
    Case "Operator"
    Worksheets("Received_Calls").Visible = True
    Worksheets("Welcome").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Users").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Reported_actions").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Parameters").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Distances").Visible = False
    Worksheets("NewCalls").Visible = False
    Worksheets("NewActions").Visible = False
Case Else
     Worksheets("Received_Calls").Visible = False
     Worksheets("Welcome").Visible = False
     Worksheets("Users").Visible = False
     Worksheets("Reported_actions").Visible = True
     Worksheets("Parameters").Visible = False
     Worksheets("Distances").Visible = False
     Worksheets("NewCalls").Visible = False
     Worksheets("NewActions").Visible = False
'need to filter
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: don't you want to look at worksheet to worksheet rather than workbook to worksheet?  Seems you have a bit of a typo:wk.Range("B3").Value = ws.Range(i, "A").Value  should be ws.Range("B3").Value = ws.Range(i, "A").Value

Comment: you can also avoid the loop by concatenating your usernames and passwords together in column C of your Users worksheet and using the match function...

Comment: souldn't `ws.Range(i, "A").Value` be `ws.Range("A" & i).Value` or `ws.Cells(i, 1).Value`

Comment: also... having a network where ppl need to log in, you can get the username from the network (in this case, they do not need to input a password)

Comment: Have you tried `application.username`?

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment yet (less than 50 rep), so I'll put this in an answer, but I'd like to address a commenter above:

sous2817 - both wk and ws are dimensioned as worksheets, so the comparison is correct.

Now to the Answer:

As Dirk states, the *workbook*.Range() function takes two arguments, but they should both be cell addresses in string format, and if both are supplied, the range returned will include all cells between them. You have:

```
ws.Range(i, "A").Value
```

which is telling excel to get cell i and cell "A" and get all cells in a square between them. This won't work because there is no such cell as "A" (and you would refer to column *A* as "A:A"), and the variable *i* will evaluate to a number (again there is no such address as 1,2,3, etc, only "1:1" etc)

What you need to change this to is, as Dirk says:

```
ws.Range("A" & i).value
```

The ampersand (&) acts as a concatenator, and will create a string for each iteration of the loop, evaluating into A1, A2, A3 etc.

You will need to do the same for the Range function that references column B as well.

Having said all that, a better solution would the answer eluded to by sous2817 in their second comment in that you could do this:

```
Dim userCell as Range
Set userCell = ws.Range("Users").Resize(,1).Find(wk.Range("B3").Value)
If userCell is nothing then
    'Username is invalid code goes here
Elseif wk.Range("B4").Value = userCell.offset(,1).value then
    'Password is valid
Else
    'Password is invalid
End If
```

As findwindow stated, you can expand upon this by first checking if the username supplied matches Application.UserName to see if it is the current windows user.

Hope this helps!